# Refresh or detect conda environments

Tags: python, refresh, updates, conda, virtual-environment

I am working in a business environment with different disks, of which on of them is my personal space (e.g. `H:\`). I created a new conda environment on that disk, and it was listed in the `conda info --envs`. Today I rebooted my machine and the conda directory is still there, but it is not anymore in the `conda info --envs` because that information is stored on a disk that gets wiped every time I log out.

I can still activate the environment by using `activate H:\path\to\env`, but not with its name. Is there a way to 'update' my conda list of environments, looking at a specific folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a directory containing environments using the command:

```
conda config --add envs_dirs /path/to/directory/containing/environments
```

On Linux:

```
(root) [root@af511ebe9357 /]# ls /condaenvs/
devops  machine_learning  so  statistics  throwaway
(root) [root@af511ebe9357 /]# conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  /conda

(root) [root@af511ebe9357 /]# conda config --add envs_dirs /condaenvs/
(root) [root@af511ebe9357 /]# conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
devops                   /condaenvs/devops
machine_learning         /condaenvs/machine_learning
so                       /condaenvs/so
statistics               /condaenvs/statistics
throwaway                /condaenvs/throwaway
root                  *  /conda

(root) [root@7d75c8c6e873 /]# cat $HOME/.condarc 
envs_dirs:
  - /condaenvs/

(root) [root@7d75c8c6e873 /]# source activate statistics
(statistics) [root@7d75c8c6e873 /]#
```

On Windows:

```
(root) C:\Users\nwani>dir F:\condaenvs
 Volume in drive F has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2B02-4CAF

 Directory of F:\condaenvs

03/10/2017  02:06 PM    <DIR>          .
03/10/2017  02:04 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/10/2017  02:05 PM    <DIR>          devops
03/10/2017  02:05 PM    <DIR>          so
03/10/2017  02:06 PM    <DIR>          machine_learning
03/10/2017  02:06 PM    <DIR>          statistics
03/10/2017  02:06 PM    <DIR>          throwaway
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  36,200,026,112 bytes free

(root) C:\Users\nwani>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  C:\Users\nwani\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda2
(root) C:\Users\nwani>conda config --add envs_dirs F:\condaenvs

(root) C:\Users\nwani>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
devops                   F:\condaenvs\devops
machine_learning         F:\condaenvs\machine_learning
so                       F:\condaenvs\so
statistics               F:\condaenvs\statistics
throwaway                F:\condaenvs\throwaway
root                  *  C:\Users\nwani\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda2


(root) C:\Users\nwani>type %USERPROFILE%\.condarc
envs_dirs:
  - F:\condaenvs

(root) C:\Users\nwani>activate statistics

(statistics) C:\Users\nwani>
```

Comment: Yep, this was what I was looking for! Thanks.